# What do I need to do to get my Java code to recognize the method Math.random()?

Tags: java

Every time I try to run a code that involves the Math.random() method I always receive the error cannot find symbol. I don't see why though because as someone stated when I asked earlier the Math class is already in the java.lang package so I don't get it. If any one could give me ideas of what I could be doing wrong or anything to fix this problem I would appreciate it because until I figure this out I can't run / or create any programs with this method involved.
Here's an example of a code that I can not get compiled due to the error:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LotteryUsingStrings {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Generate a lottery as a two-digit string
    String lottery = "" + (int)(Math.random() * 10)
      + (int)(Math.random() * 10);

    // Prompt the user to enter a guess
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter your lottery pick (two digits): ");
    String guess = input.nextLine();

    // Get digits from lottery
    char lotteryDigit1 = lottery.charAt(0);
    char lotteryDigit2 = lottery.charAt(1);

    // Get digits from guess
    char guessDigit1 = guess.charAt(0);
    char guessDigit2 = guess.charAt(1);

    System.out.println("The lottery number is " + lottery);

    // Check the guess
    if (guess.equals(lottery))
      System.out.println("Exact match: you win $10,000");
    else if (guessDigit2 == lotteryDigit1
          && guessDigit1 == lotteryDigit2)
      System.out.println("Match al digits: you win $3,000");
    else if (guessDigit1 == lotteryDigit1
          || guessDigit1 == lotteryDigit2
          || guessDigit2 == lotteryDigit1
          || guessDigit2 == lotteryDigit2)
      System.out.println("Match one digit: you win $1,000");
    else 
      System.out.println("Sorry, no match");
  }
}
```

Comment: do you have your own class called `Math`?

Comment: import the Math class

Comment: @Xoce no need - `Math` is in `java.lang`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally found the answer to my question on another site I'll link the site for other people who might also run across this problem someday. http://www.coderanch.com/t/403919/java/java/random-method-Math-class

Basically, what my problem was (as stated on this site by Ernest Friedman-Hill) is that I had, at some point, created a class named "Math" for a program I had written and those files were still around. So I needed to delete those files. However, if you have trouble locating these files you can (whenever you need to use this method) change Math.random() to java.lang.Math.random() and it will run fine. Thanks Ernest! Also thanks to the people who tried to help too!

Answer (score 0):

it compiles fine for me.

Are you using Eclipse for development? Maybe you have configured your classpath or compiler settings wrong?

Greetings
Fabian

PS: Have you tried to restart Eclipse or re-build the project?

Comment: Ok, are you programming within an editor and compiling it via the command line (with javac or similar), or are you using an IDE like Eclipse?

Comment: sorry, yes I'm programming it with a text editor (notepad)  and compiling it with the Java command Prompt.

Comment: So not Eclipse but an IDE, ok. I am working with Eclipse only so I can not help you that much as it seems to be an IDE problem. I suggest that you try to rebuild or revalidate your files, or as it is called in your IDE. Maybe you just have to save the file again?